# DeprecationWarning with xgboost

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I've installed xgboost using `whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

When I've tried:

```
import xgboost
```

And I've got next message:

> d:\program
>   files\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44:
>   DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in
>   favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored
>   classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the
>   new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module
>   will be removed in 0.20.   "This module will be removed in 0.20.",
>   DeprecationWarning)

If I print `import sklearn` prior to `import xgboost` I get no message. I assume this message won't affect the results, but how to avoid it? I've also checked via pip if all packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

### First:

**Yes,** it shall not affect the results at the moment.

### Next, how to avoid it?

Well, not an easy answer. Software evolves. Dependencies are inevitable. **Resistance is futile.** Due package & configuration management policies are the only method, how to cope with it.

### What works best for similar needs?

1. Isolate your experiments, VM-isolation is enough to build on
2. Keep using robust package management - Travis OLIPHANT's Anaconda is a way to go ( + 3 )
3. Enforce configuration management to avoid bleeding after "new"-packages get their place under sun. Anaconda allows one to "freeze" a controlled **`[environment]`**, where you define what version / release number of respective packages are kept ( and Anaconda keeps the cross-dependencies for the things there well under control, so we can just benefit from clear and well identifiable `[environment]`-s, in which the code used to run and runs further on )

Naive advice to always updates to the "latest version" simply can spoil the currently working toys and break things into havoc. It is better to explicitly define / configure / identify / enforce the fully controlled `[environment]`-s to work with and keep that for years ahead.

If one is under ISO/EN-9000+, NATO-STANAG AQAP-130+ et al, there are not much better ways to keep walking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the following commands, instead of `pip install` according to the xgboost installation guide, and the warning disappeared:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
make -j4
cd python-package
python setup.py install
```

Make sure to remove the previously installed xgboost by:

```
pip uninstall xgboost
```